# Write a MVC custom validation for specific values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a MVC custom validation. It will be valid for list of specific values. Example:

```
[Values(30, 60, 120)]
public int SelectTop { get; set; }
```

But It doesn't work with my validation. This is codes:

```
public class ValuesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public object[] Values { get; private set; }

    public Type Type { get; private set; }

    public ValuesAttribute(params int[] values)
        : this(typeof(int), values)
    {
    }

    public ValuesAttribute(params double[] values)
        : this(typeof(double), values)
    {
    }

    public ValuesAttribute(Type type, params object[] values)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Values = values;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        foreach (var v in this.Values)
        {
            if (object.Equals(v, value))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help me to find the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You're boxing value types then comparing them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
public object[] Values { get; private set; }
```

stores the array of values in it so Values[0] = int[3]

Change your code to:

```
   public override bool IsValid(object value) {
            int[] valueSet = this.Values[0] as int[];

            if (valueSet == null) {
                throw new Exception("Values must be provided");
            }

            foreach (var v in valueSet) {
                if (object.Equals(v, value)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: stores the array of values in it so Values[0] = int[3] -> happen when they are different from type.